# Splitting GeoTIFF of Mars

Tags: qgis, dem, geotiff-tiff, contour

I am trying to make a map of a terraformed Mars in QGIS and as a part of that, I need to convert [the Mars MOLA DEM](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Mars/Topography/HRSC_MOLA_Blend/Mars_HRSC_MOLA_BlendDEM_Global_200mp_v2) into contour lines at an interval of 100m. However, the file is too big for QGIS to process the entire planet so at best I have roughly 55% of the elevation data I need. I can switch to a 500m interval for the time being but what I need to do is somehow split my DEM in half - something I have not been able to figure out.

Does anyone know how I go about this?

[image: incomplete elevation data]

Comment: Create one or more polygons the size you want your cut raster to be. Than use menu raster > extraction > Clip raster by mask layer to get a clipped raster that has the size of your polygon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making two steps.It's faster using the console

Reduce the original file 11 Gb:

```
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 Mars_HRSC_MOLA_BlendDEM_Global_200mp_v2.tif result.tif

Input file size is 106694, 53347
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

he result tif is only 2.7Gb and create contour lines 100 meters :

```
gdal_contour -b 1 -a ELEV -i 100.0 -f "GPKG" result.tif OUTPUT.gpkg

0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

You can try to create the contour lines from the original file too, it will take longer but it should work

And the result is:

[image]

Contours Lines are also available thanks to OpenPlanetary,

https://openplanetary.carto.com/u/opmbuilder/tables/opm_499_mars_contours_200m_lines/public

Comment: I get a syntax error when I run the compression

Comment: What's the error?